# Removing an item from a list of items

Tags: c#, linq

My Code:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ABC ABCDetails;

        if(condition)
        {
            //ABCClient is a soap service that returns ABCDetails which consists of an array[] ABCDetails.ABCLineItemsAuto which is a list but for some reason it would show up as an array when returned from the service I check that it is declared a list in the service end.  
            ABCDetails = new ABCClient().GetABC(param1,param2).FirstOrDefault();

            foreach (var item in ABCDetails.ABCLineItemsAuto)
            {
                if (filterItemsDB.Any(c => c.itemCODE == item.itemType))
                {
                    //if its in the filterItemsDB which ia a list from databse table do something
                }
                else
                {
                    //if its not remove the item from the ABCDetails.ClaimLineItemsAuto which is an ARRAY[]

                    ABCDetails.ABCLineItemsAuto.ToList().Remove(item);
                }
            }
        }


    }
```

My Goal:

- to remove the item from the list if it does not belong to the table
  from DB

My Issue:

- the Remove(item) runs fine and does not throw any error but does not
  remove the item from ABCDetails.ABCLineItemsAuto array.

My effort:

- tried to research and find any different methods for removing an item
  from list or array none of them have this issue

Not sure whats wrong here?

I am unable to use ABCDetails.ABCLineItemsAuto.Remove(item) as the .Remove() is not available for array[] ABCDetails.ABCLineItemsAuto .

**ABCClient is a soap service that returns ABCDetails which consists of an array[] ABCDetails.ABCLineItemsAuto which is a list but for some reason it would show up as an array when returned from the service I check that it is declared a list in the service end.**

Comment: When you call `ToList()` a new `List` is instantiated. The item is being removed from this new one, but it's kept on the source. Just `ABCDetails.ABCLineItemsAuto.Remove(item)`

Comment: When you call `.ToList()` you create a copy of the list, then you remove it from the copy. Instead, you should call `.ToList()` in the `foreach` condition, then remove the item from the actual array in the body.

Comment: `I am unable to use ABCDetails.ABCLineItemsAuto.Remove(item) as the .Remove() is not available for array[] ABCDetails.ABCLineItemsAuto` <= The easiest fix is to change the type to `List<>` instead of array. That way you can modify the collection. Alternatively maybe you should not be changing it at all, that is just a guess based on the very little code you have shown us. Perhaps you do not actually need a modified array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ABCDetails.ABCLineItemsAuto.ToList().Remove(item);
```

The `ToList` actually creates a new List and removes the itme from that list. It does not alter the original list in `ABCDetails.ABCLineItemsAuto`.

You could rewrite the whole `foreach` block with 1 statement like this using [RemoveAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var lst = ABCDetails.ABCLineItemsAuto.ToList();
lst.RemoveAll(item => filterItemsDB.All(c => c.itemCODE != item.itemType));
ABCDetails.ABCLineItemsAuto = lst.ToArray();
```

This is a round about way of doing it as you just indicated that `ABCDetails.ABCLineItemsAuto` is an array.

Comment: @sss111 - glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

You have the logic slightly backwards. When you call `.ToList()`, you're creating a copy of the original list. Then when you call `.Remove()`, you're removing the item from that copy.

What you can do instead is call `.ToList()` on the item in the `foreach` condition (to avoid getting an error about modifying the enumeration), and then remove the item from the *actual* list inside the body:

**Update:** Since the type you're dealing with is an `Array`, an easy way around this is to convert it to a `List` first, since it has the handy [`Remove()`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,3d46113cc199059a,references) method. Then at the end, you can take the list and assign it back to the array if you need to. I updated the code to show how that might look:

```
var lineItemsList = ABCDetails.ABCLineItemsAuto.ToList();

// Use a copy of the list in your foreach condition
foreach (var item in lineItemsList.ToList())
{
    if (filterItemsDB.Any(c => c.itemCODE == item.itemType))
    {
        // Do something here, details aren't relevant to this question
    }
    else
    {
        lineItemsList.Remove(item);
    }
}

ABCDetails.ABCLineItemsAuto = lineItemsList.ToArray();
```

Comment: I do not have the .Remove() on the ABCDetails.ABCLineItemsAuto its an array[]

Comment: You can convert it to a [`List`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,cf7f4095e4de7646,references) first (which is basically a nice wrapper around an array). I updated the code to show how.

Answer (score 1):

The statement:

```
ABCDetails.ABCLineItemsAuto.ToList()
```

will give you a new collection i.e `List<T>` and when you are calling `Remove()` it is removing element form that new `List<T>` not from `ABCLineItemsAuto`.

What you need to do is hold that same collection as reference of `List<T>` and then call `Remove()` on it.

When we call `ToList()` we get a new `List<T>` back.

Answer (score 1):

When you call ToList() a new List is instantiated. The item is being removed from this new one, but it's kept on the source. Remove it just calling  `ABCDetails.ABCLineItemsAuto.Remove(item)`.

You can achieve this without the loop too:

```
if(condition)
{
    //ABCClient is a soap service that returns ABCDetails
    ABCDetails = new ABCClient().GetABC(param1,param2).FirstOrDefault();

    ABCDetails.ABCLineItemsAuto = ABCDetails.ABCLineItemsAuto.Except(ABCDetails.ABCLineItemsAuto.Where(i => filterItemsDB.Any(f => f.itemCODE == i.itemType)));
}
```